# Setting up Docker repository using subdomain method

Tags: docker, artifactory

docker login - how to log in only once for any docker repositories

I set up the on premise Artifactory to host some Docker repositories, using the subdomain approach, i.e. repo1.mycompany.com, repo2.mycompany.com, etc.  Everything is working fine.  My question is, look like I need to do the 'docker login repo1.mycompany.com' for each repository.  Is there a way to log in only once, for all the repositories, and then when pulling/pushing images from/to any repository, there's no need to log in again?

No code to shown here.  This is all about setup.

No need to login for each repo.

Comment: You should go through the credentials store of docker. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/

Answer (score 1):

With subdomain method each docker repository is considered as a docker registry for the client this is why you need to login to each one you want to use.

For the pull from any without login you can use a virtual repository and aggregate all your locals in it. So you'll need to login the the virtual only to be able to pull from any (through the virtual). But push will be limited to the default deployment target repo defined in the virtual one.

Another alternative is to use repo path instead of subdomains. With this approach you'll be able to login on Artifactory and use all repo :

```
docker login mycompany.com
docker pull/push mycompany.com/repo1/imageName
docker pull/push mycompany.com/repo2/imageName
```